# Selecting attribute value using XPath and HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get second attribute value of a meta tag using an xpath expression in html agility pack:
The meta tag:

```
<meta name="pubdate" content="2012-08-30" />
```

The xml path expression i am using:

```
//meta[@name='pubdate']/@content
```

But it does not return anything. I tried to search around and implement this solution:

```
//meta[@name='pubdate']/string(@content)
```

Another way:

```
string(//meta[@name='pubdate']/@content)
```

But it gives xml exception in html agility pack.
Another solution did not work as well.

```
//meta[@name='pubdate']/data(@content)
```

For reasons i wanted to use just xml path (and not html agility pack functions to get the attribute value). The function i use is below:

```
date = TextfromOneNode(document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//body"), "meta[@name='pubdate']/@content");
public static string TextfromOneNode(HtmlNode node, string xmlPath)
{
    string toReturn = "";
    if(node.SelectSingleNode(xmlPath) != null)
    {
        toReturn = node.SelectSingleNode(xmlPath).InnerText;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

So far it looks like there is no way to use xml path expression to get an attribute value directly.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/1720 suggests that attribute node selection through XPath is not supported, so you might need to select the `meta[@name='pubdate']` element node and then access its attribute as `["content"]` in C#.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have to modify the code after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way using `HtmlNodeNavigator` :

```
public static string TextfromOneNode(HtmlNode node, string xmlPath)
{
    string toReturn = "";
    var navigator = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeNavigator)node.CreateNavigator();
    var result = navigator.SelectSingleNode(xmlPath);
    if(result != null)
    {
        toReturn = result.Value;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

The following console app example demonstrates how `HtmlNodeNavigator.SelectSingleNode()` works with both XPath that return element and XPath that return attribute :

```
var raw = @"<div>
<meta name='pubdate' content='2012-08-30' />
<span>foo</span>
</div>";
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument(); 
doc.LoadHtml(raw);

var navigator = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeNavigator)doc.CreateNavigator();

var xpath1 = "//meta[@name='pubdate']/@content";
var xpath2 = "//span";

var result = navigator.SelectSingleNode(xpath1);
Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
result = navigator.SelectSingleNode(xpath2);
Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

**<kbd>[dotnetfiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q92tYf)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
2012-08-30
foo
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the modified method but there was a compilation error (something about .Value not being there). So I modified it like this. For reference if someone else is looking for the same.
`code`public static string TextfromNodeAttribute(HtmlNode node, string xmlPath)
  {
      string toReturn = "";
      var navigator = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeNavigator)node.CreateNavigator();
      var result = node.SelectSingleNode(xmlPath);
      if(result != null)
      {
       toReturn = result.GetAttributeValue("content", "");
      }
      return toReturn;
  }`code`

Comment: @MuhammadShakirAziz My bad, It was written `node.SelectSingleNode()` when it supposed to be `navigator.SelectSingleNode(...)`. I've fixed it.

Comment: This fixed it for me, finally. Looks like your method's first param should be of type `HtmlDocument`, not node.

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "<meta name=\"pubdate\" content=\"2012-08-30\" />";
            XElement meta = XElement.Parse(input);
            DateTime output = (DateTime)meta.Attribute("content");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would stick to functions provided in html agility pack.